# Whats wrong with my shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to take a local file and zip it at some other temp location.
Following is my code which is giving error

```
path="/home/tft/Downloads/ie.js"
temp="/home/tft/Downloads/Temp"
name=$(basename "$path")
echo "$path"
echo "$name"
echo "$temp"
echo "$temp/$name.zip" #Its output is also weird!
zip -r -j "$temp/$name.zip" $path
```

Getting below output:

```
 /bin/bash test.sh

/home/tft/Downloads/ie.js
ie.js
/home/tft/Downloads/Temp
.zipjstft/Downloads/Temp 
        zip warning: name not matched: /home/tft/Downloads/ie.js

)zip . -i /home/tft/Downloads/ie.js -r -j /home/tft/Downloads/Temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is in DOS format. Convert it first to UNIX format:

```
sed -i 's|\r||' yourscript.sh
```

Or use `dos2unix`:

```
dos2unix yourscript.sh
```

The error messages you see is caused by having an extra character (carriage return `\r`) at the end of your values. This happens when your file's format is not UNIX but DOS since DOS' line endings is `\r\n` where UNIX only has `\n`.

Comment: Oh great. this solved it. Never knew about it. Thanks